# Color not rendered fully while rendering in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, rendering

I want to add background color for the whole day and not the event background alone. For the code that i have written now, i could see events alone as background My view code is as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 

utc: true, 
header: { 
left: 'prev,next today EventButton', 
center: 'title', 
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
},   

editable: false, 
droppable: true, 

eventSources: ["<?php echo base_url() ?>calendar/show_holidays"]

});
});
</script>
<style>
.event-full { 
color:black;
vertical-align: middle !important;
text-align: center; 
opacity: 1; 
}

</style>
```

Now, My controller code is as follows through MVC:

```
public function show_holidays()
    {

    $holidays=$this->calendar_m->show_holidays();
    foreach($holidays as &$val){
     $val['allDay'] = 'true'; 
     $val['Rendering'] = 'Background'; 
     $val['textColor'] = '#000';
     $val['title'] = 'Holiday today' 
     $val['backgroundColor'] = 'yellow'; 
            }
     echo json_encode($holidays);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Pass this parameters as json and check this should work for you.....

```
$event['id'] = $row->id;
$event['name'] = $row->name;
$event['date'] = $row->date;
$event['backgroundColor'] = '#1ab394';
$event['rendering'] = 'background';
```

Comment: event['name'] . Isnt that event['title']..?

Comment: public function show_holidays()
    {  
        $holidays=$this->calendar_m->show_holidays();
         foreach($holidays as &$val){
         $val['allDay'] = 'true'; 
         $val['rendering'] = 'background';  
         $val['backgroundColor'] = 'red'; // added background color to all the holidays
         $val['className'] = 'holiday';
         $val['textEscape'] = 'true';
        $val['Color'] = 'black'; 
        $val['eventTextColor'] = 'white';
        // print_r($val);exit;
         $data[]=$val;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);}

Comment: the above are the actual parameters

Comment: to rendering background you dont need property name or title. Its use for events..

Comment: do you want to color the background as well as the adding background title also?

Comment: I donot want the backgroundcolor for the event , instead i want it for the whole cell.. like i have given a snapshot in the other question

Comment: use both answers by me and check. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background-color, do this, substituting 2016-05-11 for your actual date:

```
$(".fc-bg td[data-date=2016-05-11]").css("background-color", "#38ac8a");
```

You would need to do it inside fullCalendar's `viewRender` function, otherwise the change will be lost on switching views.

Comment: Inside fullcalendar.min.js?

Comment: No, inside your code. After this line - $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ - you would add viewRender: function(){}, and inside that function you loop through all days and call the line above for each of the days shown on screen.

Comment: eventSources: [ "<?php echo base_url() ?>abc/xyz/show_holidays"]

Comment: Does it make a difference? You can still have viewRender function no matter where your sources are coming from. Alternatively, you can call this line from within eventRender but that's less efficient.

Comment: ok i want the background color to the whole day only for the holidays.. in that case how to loop through inside the viewRender function(){}..

Comment: eventRender: function(event) { if (event.title === 'Holiday today') { /* then execute my code above */} }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116436/discussion-between-keynes-and-k48).